# Unclosed quotation mark after the character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I try to update my table by creating a temporary table, when I run the query in my local DB i get no issue, but when I run it in production DB I get this issue:

> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1012
> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'PostCode
> '.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1012
> Incorrect syntax near 'PostCode
> '.

Here is the line of code that throws the error:

```
INSERT [dbo].[#TempPostalCode] ([PostCode], [PostIn], [Bus], [CustomerPLId], [Box-In_Service]) 
VALUES (13189, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Update:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#TempPostalCode](
    [PostCode] [float] NULL,
    [PostIn] [float] NULL,
    [Bus] [float] NULL,
    [CustomerPLId] [float] NULL,
    [Box-In_Service] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: could you please show DDL for this temp-table

Comment: You are not showing us the original code, are you? Is it dynamic sql?

Comment: I'm guessing you're concatenating values in dynamic SQL, as your SQL has no quotation marks at all. Please show original code

Comment: (1) It better NOT to use `FLOAT` data type for integer values. **Postcode** column should be `CHAR(5)` data type.

Comment: You're leaving something out. You will need to provide the original code that produces this error, as those statements alone are valid.